# Memory chip for arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, memory

I know that you can't expand your ram because it is intern. But I want a extern memory chip (1024KBytes) that is very fast. I know that I need a library to access information on this chip. And functions to read and write data. A shield or breakout board it doesn't matter, and I want that it is compatible with Arduino mega. If the arduino lost power it doesn't matter if I lost the data. It must hold the data when the arduino is powerd.

Comment: 512mb seems quite unreasonably large for an 8-bit microcontroller. In order to get a better answer, could you explain why you need 512megabits of RAM on a chip that comes with 8kilobytes of SRAM onboard?

Comment: I've seen a lot of memory sizes, but I've never encountered a 0.5 bit memory cell. On a more serious note though, assuming you mean 512Mb, that's a ridiculous amount of memory. It would take you tens of minutes to fill up, and processing all that data would take ages. This sounds like an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: SPI RAM chips of sizes up to 128 kilobytes seem to be more realistic for you. If you really want megabytes, get a microcomputer (Rasbpi, ..) http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/memory/serial-sram-serial-nvsram

Comment: Do you mean 512Mb (Megabit) or 512MB (Megabyte)? The sizes are VERY different.

Comment: Sorry, I mean 512 KBytes or 1024KBytes. And that is not true about it is not processable. A SD card is also processable with a capacity of 4GBytes

Comment: The point is, that the Arduino would take very long to fill up the space due to it's own speed and the speed of the connection, so it might not be reasonable, to get such high capacity. SD cards for Arduinos are mostly used, because with a simple FAT implementation you can easily copy the saved data to a PC.

Comment: Could you tell us what you need it for?  There may be a more appropriate solution than adding RAM.

Answer (score 5):

You can quite easily connect multiple 128kB SPI ram chips to an Arduino. 4 of them together would give you 512kB of extra SPI-connected SRAM.

Access isn't super fast.

Another option is to use a parallel 8-bit SRAM chip. These take a lot more wiring since you need 8 wires for the data, log2(n) wires for the address, plus a couple of control wires (OE, WE, etc). But if you wire it making use of entire IO ports you can get much faster access times.  Also, these come in larger capacities than the SPI SRAM chips.

There is also PSRAM available in even bigger capacities. The same interface as SRAM but it's actually DRAM. The "P" stands for "Pseudo". You can get these in megabyte capacities, although they are usually in a BGA footprint, so you'd need to find one on a breakout board.